# query to an array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How can I do a query to an array javascript, for example I want to find all names that begin with A, an then show all information

Name":"Albert","age":"14"
Name":"Alison","age":"14"

this is my array json:

```
var house = [{"Name":"Jason","age":"43"},
{"Name":"Albert","age":"14"},
{"Name":"Luck","age":"14"},
{"Name":"Alison","age":"14"},
{"Name":"Tom","age":"12"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter an array, to collect the elements with an 'A' name, then forEach or map the matches to a new array of property names and values

```
house.filter(function(itm){
    return itm.Name.charAt(0)== 'A';
}).map(function(o){
    var A= [];
    for(var p in o){
        if(o.hasOwnProperty(p)){
            A.push(p+':'+o[p]);
        }
    }
    return A;
}).join('\n');
```

/*  returned value: (String)*/

```
Name:Albert,age:14
Name:Alison,age:14
```

If you need a shim:

```
(function(){
    var A= Array.prototype;
    if(!A.filter)   A.filter= function(fun, scope){
        var T= this, A= [], i= 0, itm, L= T.length;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i<L){
                if(i in T){
                    itm= T[i];
                    if(fun.call(scope, itm, i, T)) A[A.length]= itm;
                }
                ++i;
            }
        }
        return A;
    }
    if(!A.map) A.map= function(fun, scope){
        var T= this, L= T.length, A= Array(L), i= 0;
        if(typeof fun== 'function'){
            while(i<L){
                if(i in T){
                    A[i]= fun.call(scope, T[i], i, T);
                }
                ++i;
            }
            return A;
        }
    }
}
})();
```

Comment: for example to show the information I use a div $("#list").append(A), but It show me all, in 1 line(Name:Albert,age:14Name:Alison,age:14), how can I to it show me 1 data for line?

Comment: it's easy add br:  $("#list").append(A+"<br>")

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var result = house.filter(function(o) {
    return o.Name.indexOf("A") === 0;
});
```

Some old browsers might not support this method. Check [the compatibility and the workaround](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) at *MDN*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var names_beginning_a = house.filter(
    function (item) {return item["Name"][0].toLowerCase() === 'a';}
);
```

Once you have this, you could convert your data to a *String* using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var dataAsString = names_beginning_a.map(
    function (item) {return JSON.stringify(item);} // optionally trim off { and }
);
```

Comment: Note that the `string[i]` access method is [not supported in older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access) (IE 6 and 7, for instance). Use `string.charAt(i)` if you want to be sure.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens if they don't support `string[i]` they won't support `.map` or `.filter` or `.stringify` either and you'd need to shim all of it.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Still, you can choose to go ECMAScript 5-only, or shim those new methods and use `charAt`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function

```
arr = jQuery.grep(house, function (a) { return a.Name.indexOf("A") === 0; });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vYZBb/